# Creating a QMessageBox without Button

Tags: qt

Despite setting setStandardButtons(0); it doesn't close the msgBox.

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("My List");
msgBox.setStyleSheet("QDialog { border: 1px solid black;}");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(0);
QTimer::singleShot(5000, &msgBox, SLOT(close()));
msgBox.exec();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use accept instead of close.

```
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::NoButton);
QTimer::singleShot(5000, &msgBox, &QMessageBox::accept);
```